# Get nearby bluetooth devices in android c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to make an app that will discover all the nearby Bluetooth devices and connect to it. I have this code that will probably work in Java but I need it to work in C#:

```
public class BroadcastReciverClass : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.Action;

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ActionFound.Equals(action))
        {     
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.Add(device.Name+"  ->  "+device.Address);
            lv.Adapter = mArrayAdapter;
        }   
    }   
}
```

The problem is that Visual Studio says:

> Can't implicitly convert Java.Lang.Object to Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.
>   Are you missing a cast?

in this line:

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetParcelableExtra` is a general method that can be used to return many things. Instances of `BluetoothDevice` are only one of the things that it may return.

During compilation, the compiler doesn't know that what comes out of your call to `GetPardelableExtra` is an instance of `BluetoothDevice`. It only knows that *some* object will come out of it. So, apparently in Xamarin for Android, it simply returns a `java.lang.Object`. Only at runtime is it known that this Object contains an instance of `BluetoothDevice`.

The solution is provided in the error message; you need to cast the returned value to `BluetoothDevice`:

```
Object obj = intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
BluetoothDevice device = obj as BluetoothDevice;
if (device != null)
{
    // Rest of your code.
}
```

If the cast fails, it will return a `null`, so the null check is important.
If you get that `null` value, you will probably take some kind of action - mention it in logs or console to help you debug later.

Comment: Now when it finds a device its giving Java.NullPointerException on the runtime

Comment: @KillGeek Do you test for `null` values? Also, in these examples the `device` instance is declared inside the `if (BluetoothDevice.ActionFound.Equals(action))` block. If you want to use it outside that `if` block, you should declare it outside that `if` block.